# How to get the full path to an APK installed in an Android device

Tags: java, android, apk, dex, dexclassloader

I have an app **test.aknahs.com.dexapptest** called Dex App Test.

1. How can I get the path to the APK on install from a class **test.aknahs.com.dexapptest.TestAPKCall**,
2. How can I get the path to the APK of the app Dex App Test on install from a class **test.aknahs.com.dexapptest.TestAPKCall** in another app/ APK

both in an Android device (phones, tablets etc) and in an Emulator.

Thank you all in advance.